# Issue implementing pandas_datareader module

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader, modulenotfounderror

On MacOs
Jupyter Notebook

I'm having issues trying to implement a pandas module, I did pip list and it says that it is installed, so I'm not sure why I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-84d930aeb84e> in <module>
----> 1 from pandas_datareader import data as wb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

is there something else I need? Thanks.
I'm not sure why it's not working, I tried on VScode as well.

Comment: you need to install pandas_datareader using `pip install pandas_datareader`
Try importing after this